Elastic vs inelastic scattering in particle physics
Does elastic scattering occur via the Z boson and inelastic scattering via the W boson? If so, why? Does it have something to do with the fact that interactions via the Z boson don't change quark flavour whereas the W boson does?

Charge is conserved in W boson interactions, why do you think it isn't?

Sorry I meant quark flavour, I'll change it now.

Preserving flavor makes  elastic scattering easy, but u and d are almost degenerate, whilst  t and d are not....

What specific elastic weak scattering experiments are you looking at? Cite.

Short answer, no. In the relativistic regime, elastic scattering implies that the same particles are in your initial and final states.
Consider the elastic scattering of an electron neutrino and an electron: $\nu_e e^- \to \nu_e e^-$. There are two contributions to this process: a neutral-current scattering (exchanging a $Z$) and a charged-current scattering (exchanging a $W$). Both matter.
